# MongoDB Insertion in chunk takes varying time

Tags: mongodb

I am new to MongoDB and started doing a POC on improving the insertion time of a huge log file into MongoDB in chunks. My chunk sizes are constant (~2MB) and what I observe is out of ,say 20 chunks, all of a sudden 1 or 2 chunks in between (random) takes around 20-30% more time thank others.

I did vary the chunk size and saw this behavior kind of vanishes with lower chunk sizes. Also I did a profiling and saw a secondary thread checks for mongo db server status by pinging it and while receiving the message back from the server, the additional time is consumed. My guess is it is because of the concurrent write-lock.

Any expert advise on this and also a probably suggestion is welcome.

Thanks in advance.

The code snippet I've been using and measuring the time:

```
 DateTime dt3 = DateTime.Now;
                MongoInsertOptions options = new MongoInsertOptions();
                options.WriteConcern = WriteConcern.Unacknowledged;
                options.CheckElementNames = true;
                //var task = InsertBatchAsync<LogEvent>(collection, logEventsChunk.LogEvents);                
                collection.InsertBatch(logEventsChunk.LogEvents, options);

                Console.WriteLine("Chunk Number: " + chunkCount.ToString() + Environment.NewLine 
                    + "Write time for " + logEventsChunk.LogEvents.Count + " logs in MONGODB = " + DateTime.Now.Subtract(dt3).TotalSeconds + "s" + Environment.NewLine);
                mongoDBInsertionTotalTime += DateTime.Now.Subtract(dt3).TotalSeconds;
```

This above code snippet goes in a loop for every chunk of data I get.

Comment: You seem to be talking about sharding. Database administration is "off topic" for a programming site such as stackoverflow. You want [dba.stackexchange.com](http://dba.stackexchange.com) instead. We can answer there.

Comment: are you doing it over a network across multiple servers?  Is the ping time between servers consistent?  I assume there is a write load on your system during the chunk split/migration -- that has an impact on the times involved.

Comment: Interestingly it is all in the localhost.I have only one server instance and also 'm not using sharding.

Comment: Well, I have increased the default tcp receive and send buffer sizes to something around 500MB and till now I haven't observed the variation on insertion time. Probably that's the reason of having variation in time while copying the data stream into network stream and causing variable insertion time. Also added a static lock around the copy in the c# driver code to enable synchronous access for writing. This code also concurrently gets called by the server-status-check-ping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Increasing the buffer size for tcpClient (both send and receive) to 1GB helped. They are exposed as public properties under MongoDefault.cs.

On profiling the C# driver (Mongo) I observed the bottle neck was to copy the networkStream. So I increased the buffer and it worked.

Also, since my DB server is hosted locally I have got rid of the concurrent server status call back in the C# driver.